# How to transfer Image from tableview to second view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view with an image in each cell. I want to pass that image to a second view controller when the user selects the cell. I set up a segue from the cell to the second view controller.

My code however produces nil for the image in the second view controller.

I'm sure I'm supposed to use delegates for this and I found plenty of examples that pass them back to the first view controller but non for this way. I haven't got a clue how to set this up.

Can anyone give me an example?

TableView (First View Controller)

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "imageCropSegue"{
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? cropImageView {
            if let profileIndex = self.parseTable.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row {
                var index = NSIndexPath(forRow: profileIndex, inSection: 0)

                var cell = self.parseTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(index) as! TableViewCell
                destination.cropImage.image = cell.cellImage.image //throws an exception as destination.cropImage = nil
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Second view controller

```
class cropImageView:UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var cropImage: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}
```

Comment: step by step tutorial to pass data to next view controller in swift http://jamesleist.com/ios-swift-passing-data-between-viewcontrollers/

Comment: you can use Observer

Comment: pass `UIImage` don't set from from first view. set it from viewDidLoad of second view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second View controller:

```
class cropImageView:UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var cropImage: UIImageView!
    var selectedImage : UIImage?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.cropImage.image = self.selectedImage //Assign selected Image here

    }
}
```

*PrepareForSegue* method in FirstView controller be like:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "imageCropSegue"{
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? cropImageView {
            if let profileIndex = self.parseTable.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row {
                var index = NSIndexPath(forRow: profileIndex, inSection: 0)

                var cell = self.parseTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(index) as! TableViewCell
                //destination.cropImage.image = cell.cellImage.image //Change here

               destination.selectedImage= cell.cellImage.image
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never try to update any UI from segue, always pass Image name from segue and or you can pass Index of your array and after that in your next View controller you can assign that Image to your `ImageView` in `ViewDidLoad` method.

In your code you are trying to assign Image from your FirstViewController with this code:

```
destination.cropImage.image = cell.cellImage.image
```

this is not good way to assign image. Instead of that you can just pass ImageName from first view to second view from your imageName array like this:

```
destination.imageName = yourImageNameArrya[index]
```

and Into your second view controller you have to add one instance which hold this name like shown below:

```
class cropImageView:UIViewController{

    let imageName = ""   //This will hold your image name

    @IBOutlet weak var cropImage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        cropImage.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The cropImage is not initialized in the prepareForSegue method. Try to store the image into a field of cropImageView, and set it to the cropImage.image in the viewDidLoad() lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @mayank-jain for the tutorial.

http://jamesleist.com/ios-swift-passing-data-between-viewcontrollers/

This was so simple in the end. It never occurred to me to pass it to a variable first.